# Update panel fails across network

Tags: c#, asp.net, ajax, iis-8

What happens is on postback IE encounters the error

> > Unable to get property 'PRM_ServerError' of undefined or null reference

This error only occurs when the project is deployed onto a remote machine and only in IE.  I am unsure as to why this is as when the project is deployed locally it executes correctly in IE.  Furthermore when I access the website locally from the remote server it does not encounter this issue.  At first I believed it was a security issue however the website executes in the same security zone regardless of where it is deployed.  Any ideas? Thanks.

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" MasterPageFile="~/Site.Master" CodeBehind="test.aspx.cs" Inherits="UnitConverterWrapperDemo.Controllers.KcclWrapper" %>
<asp:Content ID="BodyContent" ContentPlaceHolderID="MainContent" runat="server">
    <h1>Wrapper Test</h1>
    <br />
    <h3>Calculation</h3>
    <asp:UpdatePanel runat="server">
        <ContentTemplate>
            <asp:DropDownList ID="Calculation" runat="server" CssClass="form-control" AutoPostBack="true" OnSelectedIndexChanged="Calculation_SelectedIndexChanged"></asp:DropDownList>
        </ContentTemplate>
    </asp:UpdatePanel>
    <asp:Panel runat="server">
        <script type="text/javascript">
            $('#tab a:first').tab('show');

            $('#calcOptions').click(function (e) {
                e.preventDefault()
                $(this).tab('show')
            })
            $('#Inputs').click(function (e) {
                e.preventDefault()
                $(this).tab('show')
            })
        </script>
        <br />

        <ul class="nav nav-tabs" id="tab">
            <li class="active"><a href="#calcOptions" data-toggle="tab" class="active">Options</a></li>
            <li><a href="#Inputs" data-toggle="tab">Inputs</a></li>
            <li><a href="#Constants" data-toggle="tab">Constants</a></li>
            <li><a href="#Intermediate" data-toggle="tab">Intermediate</a></li>
            <li><a href="#Output" data-toggle="tab">Outputs</a></li>
        </ul>

        <br />

        <div class="tab-content">
            <div class="tab-pane active" id="calcOptions">
                <asp:UpdatePanel runat="server">
                    <ContentTemplate>
                        <asp:Label Text="text" runat="server" ID="OptionsHeader" />
                        <fieldset>
                            <asp:Panel runat="server" ID="Options"></asp:Panel>
                        </fieldset>
                        <hr />
                    </ContentTemplate>
                </asp:UpdatePanel>
            </div>
            <div class="tab-pane" id="Inputs">
                <asp:UpdatePanel runat="server">
                    <ContentTemplate>
                        <asp:Panel runat="server" ID="inputs">
                        </asp:Panel>
                    </ContentTemplate>
                </asp:UpdatePanel>
            </div>

            <div class="tab-pane" id="Constants">
                <asp:UpdatePanel runat="server">
                    <ContentTemplate>
                        <asp:Panel runat="server" ID="constrants">
                        </asp:Panel>
                    </ContentTemplate>
                </asp:UpdatePanel>
            </div>

            <div class="tab-pane" id="Intermediate">
                <asp:UpdatePanel runat="server">
                    <ContentTemplate>
                        <asp:Panel runat="server" ID="intermediate">
                        </asp:Panel>
                    </ContentTemplate>
                </asp:UpdatePanel>
            </div>

            <div class="tab-pane" id="Output">
                <asp:UpdatePanel runat="server">
                    <ContentTemplate>
                        <asp:Panel runat="server" ID="output">
                        </asp:Panel>
                    </ContentTemplate>
                </asp:UpdatePanel>

                <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg">Recalculate</button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </asp:Panel>
</asp:Content>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For those interested, I was getting the same error on my page immediately after deploying to our production web server.

The error occurs during ajax calls inside your update panel when some server-side code is called, but the iis app pool has been recycled (which happens after a deployment).

The error can be handled in code by adding the AsyncPostBackError event handler to your ScriptManager.

You can then redirect the user somewhere when this error occurs or display a popup message saying their session has expired and is now refreshed or whatever suits your application.

More info here: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb398934.aspx

Hope this helps someone :)